# Python :print the cumulative sum of x along axies 0 and 1

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

create a  array of x shape (5,6) having 30 random integer between -30 and 30

```
print the cumulative sum of x along axies 0

print the cumulative sum of x along axies 1
```

The out expected is 9 and -32.

I tryed with below code

```
 import numpy as np
 np.random.seed(100)
 l1= np.random.randint(-30,30, size=(5,6))
 x= np.array(l1)
 print(x.sum(axis=0))
 print(x.sum(axis=1))
```

can you please help  me what is wrong with this?

Comment: So what happened?  Wrong answer?  Error?  Show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of your expressions are:

```
x.sum(axis=0)  ==  array([ -9, -58, -38,  40,  16,   9])
x.sum(axis=1)  ==  array([-68,  47,   1,  12, -32])
```

As you wrote the expected results are *9* and *-32*, maybe you want
to compute sums of the **last column** and **last row**?

To get just these results, compute:

```
x[:, -1].sum()    (yields 9)
x[-1, :].sum()    (yiels -32)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

def array_oper(num1, num2):
    
    np.random.seed(100)
    x = np.random.randint(num1, num2+1, size=(5, 6))
    cumsum_axis0 = np.cumsum(x, axis=0)
    print(cumsum_axis0[0][-1])
    cumsum_axis1 = np.cumsum(x, axis=1)
    print(cumsum_axis1[:,0][-1])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.